# Is the set described below disconnected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose we have an everywhere-positive function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with just one discontinuous point. Is the set consisting of the graph of $f$ and the $x$-axis disconnected?

I guess the answer is yes. However, I have no ideas proving the general case.

Comment: One of the cases I am considering is f(x)=lxl for x≠0 and f(x)=1. If the discontinuity is a jump, I guess it will be a isolated point and thus the set is disconnected. But, what if the discontinuity is an oscillation like sin(1/x)?

Comment: What you're asking is if the set $\{(x,0) : x\in\Bbb R\}\,\cup\,\{(x,f(x)) : x\in\Bbb R\}$ is disconnected and you mean disconnected in the sense of $X = A\cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint open sets?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is never equal to $0$ the set is obviously disconnected

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: it does not have to be disconnected. Your $\sin(1/x)$ idea is a good intuition, you just have to tweak it a bit in order to satisfy your constraints.

First for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$ define

$$f(1/n)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }n\text{ is odd} \\
|1/n| & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

then extend it to full $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ piecewise linearly (for $|x|>1$ make it constant $1$) and finally define $f(0)=1$. So this is a "saw", bounded above by $1$ and below by $\min(|x|, 1)$.

The crucial observation is that any neighbourhood of $(0,1)$ and any neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ contains a fragment of $f$'s graph.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a counterexample: $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1-x  & x\leq 0 \\
 x + \sin^2 \frac{1}{x} & x > 0 \end{cases}.$$

Any open neighborhood of the points $(0, 1)$ or $(0, 0)$ must include parts of the sine curve to the right, so the function graph plus the $x$-axis cannot be separated into multiple open sets.